# Update nested elements using ASP.NET core with json patch

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, json-patch

Anybody know how to update nested elements of items using asp.net core json patch?

I'm tried to use 
`xx.Operations.Add(new Operation<DataRequestModel>("Replace", $"schedules/{scheduleId}/status", null, DataRequestStatusEnum.ExtractionFailed));`

But it throws an exception `The path segment '43688769-f45e-4e84-a8d6-f071c077b9ad' is invalid for an array index.` when I use `model.ApplyTo(dataRequest);` in patch action.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I did that by using

**Controller**

```
    [Route("{some}/adress")]
    [HttpPatch]
    public bool YourDtoUpdate(long some, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<TestpDTO> testChanges)
    {
        var tsd = new TestDTO(){Nested = new NestedClass()};
        testChanges.ApplyTo(tsd);
    }
```

**Service**

```
    var model = new TestDTO() { Foo = "abc", Nested = new NestedClass()};
    JsonPatchDocument<TesDTO> patchDoc = new JsonPatchDocument<TestDTO>();
    patchDoc.Replace(e => e.Foo , model.Foo );
    patchDoc.Replace(e => e.Nested.Bar, model.Nested.Bar);
```